# Specifying Legal and/or Illegal Implicits at Compile-time?

Tags: scala, implicit

Let's say that I have two particular `object`'s from which I retrieve imports. Assume that both objects have multiple, useful imports that I want to use. I'm only including 1 for simplicity of this example:

```
scala> object Implicits1 { implicit def good: String => Int = _ => 42 }
defined object Implicits1

scala> object Implicits2 { implicit def bad: String => Int = _ => 666 }
defined object Implicits2
```

Then, given `foo`:

```
scala> def foo(x: Int): Int = x
foo: (x: Int)Int
```

I perform my wildcard imports to get implicits:

```
scala> import Implicits1._
import Implicits1._

scala> import Implicits2._
import Implicits2._
```

Running `foo(".")` on the REPL shows that `Implicits2.bad`'s implicit was resolved:

```
scala> foo(".")
res0: Int = 666
```

But, I actually wanted `Implicits1.good`, not `Implicits2.bad`.

som-snytt and Shadowlands educated me on how to handle wildcard imports - [Wildcard Import, then Hide Particular Implicit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32661654/wildcard-import-then-hide-particular-implicit).

However, can I specify at compile-time that particular implicits are allowed or forbidden?

Answer (score 2):

Testing this in REPL will give wrong results. If you had both imports in a file, you'd get an ambiguous implicit error. Beyond this

> can I specify at compile-time that particular implicits are allowed

Import them.

> or forbidden

Don't import them. If

> both objects have multiple, useful imports that I want to use

then you can say ["import everything except these specific identifiers"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871822/how-do-i-exclude-rename-some-classes-from-import-in-scala):

```
import Implicits2.{bad => _, bad2 => _, _}
```

If you *have* brought an implicit into scope, the only way to disable it is by shadowing, as in the linked question.